# Expose my docker container to my external IP on GCP

Tags: nginx, docker, containers, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

We have a dockerized app that we imported on a Compute Engine instance with ubuntu 16.04.
It contains a nginx reverse proxy running on port 80 and in /etc/hosts we've added 127.0.0.1   mydockerizedapp

The GCE got an external IP address.
How can I set so that when I go on this external IP from a browser, I see the files served by the container nginx ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to [expose the ports of your container](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/deploying-docker-containers) on the host machine by mapping it.

If you use the cli: `--port-mappings=80:80:TCP`

Comment: thanks it fixed the issue, but now have another issue, the reverse proxy in the container doesn't work, will post a new question. Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the command that you run with that flag to be able to map the port to the host machine?